# Binding to c# some java-code, that uses .so libraries

Tags: java, c#, binding, aar, .so

There are some .so libraries and java code uses them for android.

I compile this java code within android studio to get an .aar file. I need to make binding for c# code fo Xamarin.Android using Visual Studio. So, while binding with java is working good, the java code throws exception:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Through the seeing of full exception message I got that java code can't find .so files. In the Android Studio project .so libs are settled at ./lib/armeabi-v7a/, and the java code works well.

So, the question is: where should I put .so libs in C# binding library? Some inner scent tips me I should put it somewhere -- that's the way libraries work.

I've tried to put .so libraries in directory with my .dll, also deeper in ./lib/armeabi-v7a/, but it actually didn't help -- the exception was the same. I've tried to put them in the directory with my .aar file and also in the deeper directory in ./lib/armeabi-v7a/ but this is kinda of shamanism. it's also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the way I tried to check the work of program. My Android emulator didn't have the armeabi-v7a support. After I tried to change my emulator settings. it became laggy and very slow. The issue was to test an application on real device.